# How to make check box being optional to check or can be check all of them?

Tags: php, html

I am having this error when I don't check one of my checkbox in my php form how to make it optional and also accepts even they checked it all?
Warning: Undefined array key "edu2"

```
<body>
<form>
        <div class="edu">
        Illiterate
            <input type="checkbox" name="edu1" value="Illiterate">
        Person with Disability
            <input type="checkbox" name="edu2" value="Person with Disability">
        Indigenous People
            <input type="checkbox" name="edu3" value="Indgenous People">
        </div>

        <div class="info">
        Date of Birth:
            <input type="date" name="bday" required>
        Place of Birth:
            <input type="text" name="bdayplace" required>
        Contact Number:
            <input type="tel" name="cnum" required>
        Age:
            <input type="number" name="age" required>
        Gender:
        <div class="rdb">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other
        </div>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        print_r($_POST);
        #status
        $check = $_POST['edu1'];
        $check = $_POST['edu2'];
        $check = $_POST['edu3'];
        #info
        $date = $_POST['bday'];
        $name = $_POST['bdayplace'];
        $tel = $_POST['cnum'];
        $number = $_POST['age'];
        $radio= $_POST['gender'];
        #otherinfo
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $name = $_POST['rel'];
        $radio= $_POST['civil'];
    }   
    ?>
</body>
```

tried to search on how to make checkbox optional on handling php and validation also

Comment: Missing a `<form>` element

Comment: You're also overwriting `$check` twice

Comment: what do you mean overwriting $check sir?

Comment: Now that you added a `<form>` element you're still missing `method="post"` to make `$_POST` available in your PHP

Comment: `$check = $_POST['edu1']; $check = $_POST['edu2']; $check = $_POST['edu3'];` will overwrite `$check`

Comment: @Kael made this for you if still needed. https://codepen.io/PhilAndelhofs/pen/QWadyNX

Answer (score 2):

If checkbox is not checked, then no information will be sent to server.

That's why you got error `Warning: Undefined array key "edu2"`.

You should check if key is present in `$_POST`:

```php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    #status
    $check = $_POST['edu1'] ?? false;
    $check = $_POST['edu2'] ?? false;
    $check = $_POST['edu3'] ?? false;
}
```

---

**Please note** that you are using same name for all `edu*` values, so final result of `$check` will always be from `$check = $_POST['edu3'] ?? false;`

Comment: What can I do to make it accept 2 values like it can accept Illiterate and also person with disability?

Comment: @Kael Depends on how you going to use it. Maybe rename to `$edu1`, `$edu2` and `$edu3`, maybe do `$check = !empty($_POST['edu1']) || !empty($_POST['edu2'])`